# Posting a form with action attribute causes page to change url

Tags: angularjs

I have this form:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" action="/api/project" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="prj_title"  ng-model="project.prj_title" >
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg" value="Request">
</form>
```

It works, but problem is the url changes to /api/project. I don't want this. I just want to post my data to /api/project.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omit the action attribute and do all the logic through your `submit` method

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
<input type="text" name="prj_title"  ng-model="project.prj_title" >
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg" value="Request">
```

You don't need it, since Angular does the major work here

Quote from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit):

> Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), **but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.**